# Difference between different project files in Netbeans

Tags: file, netbeans, project, markup

I have in my working environment always more then one project open, some of the have same files but are from different project, and finding out which of them are from which project can be a real pain in the ass(however 2 sec over the div and see which folder are they from)

Is there a way to mark them so i can tell which file is from which project?

I am using NB 7.3 64bit for Windows.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin which shows the path in the title: http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/42000/show-path-in-title

And if you are switching files via CTRL+Tab the path of the selected file is shown on the bottom of the window.
Maybe this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The window title for me is: "{project name} - NetBeans IDE 7.2.1". Directly on the tab I don't know how to put this information, but I use "View -> show versioning labels". Instead of various projects open, I have various "instances" of the same project on different branches in my VCS.

I'm using Ubuntu.

**UPDATE**

Just reinstalled NetBeans 7.3 on a Windows VM and the behavior is the same: project name prepends "NetBeans IDE {version}" in window Title.